# set pandas plot config default

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way to set a default configuration, e.g. `figsize` when using `pandas.DataFrame.plot` method? I am looking for something like `matplotlib.pyplot.rcParams['figure.figsize']`

Comment: The plot method on `Series` and `DataFrame` is just a simple wrapper around `plt.plot()`. That means that importing `rcParams` and setting `rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [valuex, valuey]` will do the job

Comment: @joaquin thanks. I just tried it again and it works. I guess I made some mistakes when I set the params it which is why it didn't change the `dataframe.plot` size.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this before plot method invocation:

```py
# required on Jupiter Notebook
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib as mpl
width, height = 15, 6 # example with 15x6 inches
mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [width, height]
```

See [this post](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html?highlight=figure.figsize#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file) for details.